# What is in Russian "login throttling"

Tags: информатика

There is a paragraph in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication):

> And finally, login throttling: that is, setting a time delay between
>   attempts after N failed attempts (yes, DoS attacks are still possible,
>   but at least they are far less likely and a lot more complicated to
>   pull off).

I know what does it mean, so I need no explanations. I have the only one question: is there a specific term in Russian for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern informatics term are hard to translate because there is no official body that regulates this field in Russia, plus usually IT specialists are proficient in English so that they don't need translations and use original info.

I'd translate this as:

> Логин с задержкой обработки
>
> Логин с таймаутом